# Issue where newly tabs ionic starter project simply crashes on ios simulator and ios device. But works if used ionic serve

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I installed a starter ionic tab project on mac. After building the app and running "ionic cordova run ios" command the app crashes on ios simulator and ios device. I guess its crashes as it just opens for a second and closes itselft. Not sure whats causing this to happen. The same app works if I use "ionic serve". Can someone please help us in resolving this issue?

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1101.4
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.1.4
@angular/cli                  : 11.1.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : none
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res (update available: 0.15.3) : 0.15.1
native-run (update available: 1.3.0)   : 0.3.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 24.4.1 (/Users/WashConnect/Library/Android/sdk)
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
NodeJS            : v13.7.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.7.0/bin/node)
npm               : 7.5.4
OS                : macOS Mojave
Xcode             : Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504

Comment: did you add any code in it or it is just new project?

Comment: Whatever came with the starter tab project. I didn't added any extra code. It works if I use ionic serve. The 3 different tabs shows up in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Ionic instructions for iOS Development](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/ios#running-with-xcode), you should first open the project in Xcode and run from there (rather than using the CLI). This will allow you to fix any signing issues, [add a development team to your app](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/ios#setting-up-a-development-team), etc.

You will find the project within the `platforms/ios` folder - the file will have the extension `.xcodeproj`. Once you have completed this process through Xcode, it should work from the command line in future.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I was able to make it work in the simulator. But I having a different issue where the app looks correct in the simulator but if install on the phone it shows all black background.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The solution was for me to

- uninstall statusbar plugins of cordova and capacitor from the project
- uninstall splashscreen plugins of cordova and capacitor from the project
- remove all references to these two plugins from package.json en app.module.ts

then compile again (npm run build) and the issue is solved.
Hopefully this will also help you.